# Allow Indian and US phone numbers in Laravel 5.4

Tags: regex, laravel-5.4

I want to allow only some specific types of phone number format.
Ex:

1. **xxx-xxx-xxxx**
2. **+91-xxxxxxxxxx**.

I don't know what will be the regular expression for this.
I refered some sites and got this

```
/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/
```

which works for 1st one but not worked for +91 format.

Basically, I want to allow India and US numbers only.

**2nd Question:**

I want a regular expression which will allow +, -, (, ), and the numbers i.e. 0-9 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that accept your inputs, with separators , `.` and `-`:

```
\+91[\s-]\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[\s-]\d{3}[\s-]\d{4}
```

### [Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/biIlIx/3)

The following inputs are valid:

```
123-456-7890
123 456 7890
(123) 123-6547
(999)-999-9999
+91-1234567890
+91 1234567890
```

If you only want to accept `-` as a separator, change all `[\s-]` by `-` in the regex.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly expect the .(dot)  one. I dont want to allow +91.9966666666 or 999.999.9999

Comment: @Saroj Ok, I've removed dots from my answer ;P

Answer (score 1):

are u looking for something like `^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\+91 \d{10})`
[example](https://regex101.com/r/v9jSh5/3) 
both numbers are placed in group one this way if u work with groups

*edit:*

are u looking for one like this? this allows the sets of numbers to be seperated with everything exept a letter or a number 
`(\d{3}[^\d\w]\d{3}[^\d\w]\d{4}|\+91[^\d\w]\d{10})`
[example](https://regex101.com/r/v9jSh5/7)

Comment: This allowed first one but not the next one.

Comment: @Saroj Then just add a hyphen between \+91 and \d{10}

Comment: Thanks what about (123) 123-6547 & (999)-999-9999